# form is being replaced when it shouldn't be

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have an application you can access here: [application](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/Text96.php)

Now in the app, leave the module drop down menu to the `Please Select` option and submit. You will see a message appear stating to select a module. So now select a module from the drop down and submit. You can see it shows an `Assessment` drop down menu underneath (assessments which are related to that module).

Now I want the `Assessment` drop down menu to perform the same way as the `Module` drop down menu. If no assessment is selected then display a message underneath, if assessment is chosen then display the next form underneath, with the `Assessment` drop down menu and submit still showing like the `Module` drop down menu and submit is still showing on the page.

Problem is though as you will be able to see if you do or not select an assessment option is that instead it gets replaced by the next form block (showing multiple select box). I want the select box to not be displayed if user has not chosen an assessment in drop down menu when submitted or display it underneath the assessment drop down menu and submit button if assessment is chosen, not replace it.

But what is causing this and can I get it to perform the functionality it should do?

Below is a shortened version of the code:

Code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">


    function validation(e) {

                    var isDataValid = true;

                    var moduleTextO = document.getElementById("modulesDrop");

                    var errModuleMsgO = document.getElementById("moduleAlert");

             if (moduleTextO.value == ""){
              $('#targetdiv').hide();
              $('#assessmentForm').hide();
              errModuleMsgO.innerHTML = "Please Select a Module";
              isDataValid = false;    
            }else{
                    errModuleMsgO.innerHTML = ""; 
                    $('#assessmentForm').show();
                }

                    if (isDataValid === false)
        {
            if (e.preventDefault)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();//VERY important
            }
            e.returnValue = false;
            e.cancelBubble = true;
        }

                return isDataValid;

                }


                function sessionvalidation(e) {

                    var isDataValid = true;

                    var sessionTextO = document.getElementById("sessionsDrop");

                    var errAssesMsgO = document.getElementById("assessmentAlert");

             if (sessionTextO.value == ""){
              $('#assessmentdiv').hide();
              $('#studentExistForm').hide();
              errAssesMsgO.innerHTML = "Please Select an Assessment";
              isDataValid = false;    
            }else{
                    errAssesMsgO.innerHTML = ""; 
                    $('#studentExistForm').show();   
                     $('#assessmentForm').show();
                }

                    if (isDataValid === false)
        {
            if (e.preventDefault)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();//VERY important
            }
            e.returnValue = false;
            e.cancelBubble = true;
        }

                return isDataValid;

                }


                </script>

        <?php

    $moduleHTML  = "";  
    $moduleHTML .= '<select name="modules" id="modulesDrop">'.PHP_EOL;
    $moduleHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;  
    $moduleHTML .= '</select>'; 


        ?>


    <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" onsubmit="return validation(event);">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <th>Module: <?php echo $moduleHTML; ?></th>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <p><input id="moduleSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit Module" name="moduleSubmit" /></p>
    <div id="moduleAlert"></div>
    <div id="targetdiv"></div>
    </form>

    <?php

    if (isset($_POST['moduleSubmit'])) {    

     $moduleInfo = explode("_", $_POST['modules']);
     $moduleNo = $moduleInfo[0];
     $moduleName = $moduleInfo[1];
     $moduleId = $moduleInfo[2];
     $outputmodule = sprintf("<p><strong>Selected Module:</strong> %s - %s <input type='hidden' value='%s'></p>", $moduleNo, $moduleName, $moduleId);


    $sessionHTML = '';  
    $sessionHTML = '<select name="session" id="sessionsDrop">'.PHP_EOL;
    $sessionHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;           
    $sessionHTML .= sprintf("<option value='%s'>%s - %s - %s</option>", $dbSessionId, $dbSessionName, date("d-m-Y",strtotime($dbSessionDate)), date("H:i",strtotime($dbSessionTime))) . PHP_EOL;            
    $sessionHTML .= '</select>';

    $assessmentform = "<div id='lt-container'>
    <form action='".htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."' method='post' id='assessmentForm'>
    {$outputmodule}
    <p><strong>Assessments:</strong> {$sessionHTML} </p>  
    <p><input id='assessmentSubmit' type='submit' value='Submit Assessment' name='assessmentSubmit' /></p>
    <div id='assessmentAlert'></div>
    <div id='assessmentdiv'></div> 
    </form>
    </div>";

    echo $assessmentform;

    }

    if (isset($_POST['assessmentSubmit'])) {     

    $studentHTML = '';      
    $studentSELECT = '<select name="studenttextarea" id="studentselect" size="6">'.PHP_EOL;      
    $studentSELECT .= "<option disabled='disabled' class='red' value=''>No Students currently in this Assessment</option>"; 
    $studentSELECT .= sprintf("<option disabled='disabled' value='%s'>%s - %s %s</option>", $dbStudentId, $dbStudentAlias, $dbStudentForename, $dbStudentSurname) . PHP_EOL;    
    $studentSELECT .= '</select>';

    $studentexist="
    <form id='studentExistForm'>
    <p><strong>Current Active Students in Assessment:</strong></p>
    <p>{$studentSELECT}</p>
    </form> 
    </div>";

    echo $studentexist;

    }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it isn't showing the second section is because when you click on the assessment submit form, `$_POST['moduleSubmit']` will not be set.

You could change

`if (isset($_POST['moduleSubmit']))`

to

`if (isset($_POST['moduleSubmit']) || isset($_POST['assessmentSubmit']))`

So that it shows that section if either are set (either form submitted)

Comment: Hi, so do i need to just replace that line you mentioned to the new line you mentioned? Do I need to remove the `if (isset($_POST['assessmentSubmit'])){ }` code or do I keep it?

Comment: Yes, just replace it. And yes, you still need the second line of code. From my understanding, you want the assessment selection to appear when they have chosen a module and selected an assessment. You only want the multi select when the assessment is submitted.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am encountering other problems so I might need to change my design a bit but you have answered the question correctly :)